# How can I use complex binding to get keys displayed rather then values from key value pairs in view.xml

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, sapui5

I know I can use complex binding to display values using keys from my model. Which is json object. But how can i print all the keys without knowing how many of them are there.

I tried searching for the solution in google but nothing similar is present.

```
<f:Form id="SimpleFormDisplay354" editable="true">
   <f:toolbar>
      <OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
         <Title text="Details" level="H2"/>
         <ToolbarSpacer/>
         <Button icon="sap-icon://decline" press="handleSideContentHide"/>
      </OverflowToolbar>
   </f:toolbar>
   <f:layout>
      <f:ResponsiveGridLayout/>
   </f:layout>
   <f:FormContainer>
      <f:formElements items="{path: '/'}">
         <f:FormElement label="{label}">
            <f:fields><Input placeholder="Send Text" type="Text" width="50%"/></f:fields>
         </f:FormElement>
      </f:formElements>
   </f:FormContainer>
</f:Form>
```

I want to know what should I be writing instead of {label} to display keys.

Comment: JSON objects are written in key/value pairs and each value is identify using the `key` only. As per the UI5 binding is concern we need the key to bind the values. You can add an extra `key` like `labelText` which holds the `key` text.

Comment: Kindly share your JSON object

Comment: @inizio yeah this cool like a nice hack .. will quickly try this and let you know if this resolves my problem... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem is I dynamically added the elements in my formContainer using my controller.js.

```
for (var key in oValues) {

     if(oValues.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           var oFormElement = new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement().addField(new sap.m.Input({value:oValues[key]}));
           oFormElement.setLabel(key);                                                               
           this.byId("id_of_FormContainerinXML").addFormElement(oFormElement);
             }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys of the JSON objet with `Object.keys(JsonObject)`.

```
const json = {"name": "Bob", "age": "35"};
const aKeys = Object.keys(json); // => aKeys = ["name", "age"]
const aItems= aKeys.map(key => {return {label: key}})
```

Save aItems to a JSONModel and bind to that.